# file chooser not working in Android WebView with all platforms

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have gone through so many solutions/library to upload a file from Android WebView but in each and every solution/library there is one common problem that does not work with all the different Android API.

1. Some solution works only for > Android 4.4
2. Some work only for < Android 4.4
3. Some do not work for Samsung devices
4. Some do not work for Honeycomb

and many more....

**Is there any solutions or library which will work for all the platforms?**

***PLEASE DO NOT DOWNVOTE FOR THIS QUESTION. MAY BE THE WAY I ASK IS NOT GOOD BUT IT IS VERY IMPORTANT FOR ME.***